# I'm having a difficulty in the application intalled menu

Tags: upgrade, application-development, uninstall, appmenu, default-programs

How can I see all the installed application collectively except the default ones

If there's not, please make one because it's hard to know if its a default or a installed one. And a default programs button.

Thanks!

Comment: "If there's not, please make one" We do not make Ubuntu. We use it so what you ask here we can not create for you ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request and not a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Unity Applications Lens** from **Dash**:

[image: Unity Applications Lens]

Also, in **Ubuntu Software Center**, **History** tab, there is a list with all installed applications by date and time:

[image: Ubuntu Software Center - History]